# How to execute a python file from android studio?

Tags: python, android-studio, plugins

I'm trying to execute a python file from android studio, all i need to do is to send a string to a python file x.py from y.java(in android studio), execute x.py and send output back to the y.java.
I have installed Python Communtiy Plugin from plugin option in android studio, but it does not response to any python script. I have gone through Project Structure, but there were no platform setting options.
How can i solve it ? Please help.

Comment: why don't you call an API instead, what you want to do is really a bad idea

Comment: I was thinking of same, have tried all simple methods but nothing worked. How about REST APIs? I have less idea about how to create REST APIs, if you could tell me the idea!